# Occasional exception "No view found" for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash

Occasionally, my app crashes with the following exception:

```
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b00d5 for fragment FragmentSettingsDetailWebService{41bd6408 #0 id=0x7f0b00d5}
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-12 08:42:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(2549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying to understand if this is a flaw in Android, or something that I am doing.  I have an xml file named `FragmentSettingsDetailWebService` in both folders:

- layout
- layout-land

So, the view exists in both orientations.  It appears to be a timing issue.  It does not occur very often, once every few weeks actually, but I want to understand what is happening to avoid it if at all possible.  Might this be an Android issue?  It has occurred in all versions of Android 4.0 and higher.

Please advise

Comment: Have you been able to identify which view corresponds to id 0x7f0b00d5?

Comment: @helleye  Unfortunately not - given the rarity of the event, I have not found a way do do so.  When the event occurs all logging stops.  Since I cannot recreate (at least not how it's happening), I have not been able to capture that data.